# How to reduce column number by removing all na values and shifting values forward: R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a dataset in R where I would like to shift all values to the left by removing the NAs and remove the extra number of columns after. Ideally, I would also like the columns to be relabeled.

```
df <- data.frame(path_finalcode = c(1, 2, 3, 4), `99210` = c("99210", 
NA, NA, NA), `102300` = c(NA, "102300", NA, NA), `1352816` = c(NA, 
NA, "1352816", NA), `1810151` = c(NA, "1810151", NA, NA))
```

I would like such that the expected dataframe look something like this

```
df <- data.frame(path_finalcode = c(1, 2, 3, 4), col1 = c("99210", 
"102300", "1352816", NA), col2 = c(NA, "1810151", NA, NA))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R:

```r
res <- apply(df[,-1], 1, na.omit, simplify = FALSE)
res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(res, `length<-`, max(lengths(res))))
colnames(res) <- paste0("col", seq_len(ncol(res)))
cbind(df[,1,drop=FALSE], res)
#   path_finalcode    col1    col2
# 1              1   99210    <NA>
# 2              2  102300 1810151
# 3              3 1352816    <NA>
# 4              4    <NA>    <NA>
```

Data

```r
df <- structure(list(path_finalcode = c(1, 2, 3, 4), X99210 = c("99210", NA, NA, NA), X102300 = c(NA, "102300", NA, NA), X1352816 = c(NA, NA, "1352816", NA), X1810151 = c(NA, "1810151", NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to collapse all the columns into one using `unite` and then separate them using `separate_wider_delim` into separate columns to append `NA` at the end.

```
library(tidyr)

df |>
  unite(col, -path_finalcode, na.rm = TRUE) |>
  separate_wider_delim(col, "_", names = paste0("col", 1:2), 
                       too_few = "align_start")

#  path_finalcode col1      col2   
#           <dbl> <chr>     <chr>  
#1              1 "99210"   NA     
#2              2 "102300"  1810151
#3              3 "1352816" NA     
#4              4 ""        NA
```

In the above solution output columns are hardcoded (`paste0("col", 1:2)`). If you do not know how many columns your data would have and want it to be dynamic you can take help of `str_count` to calculate that. The solution would then change to -

```
df1 <- df |> unite(col, -path_finalcode, na.rm = TRUE)

# Count the number of underscores and add +1 to it because
# 1 underscore means 2 numbers, 2 underscore means 3 numbers and so on.
cols <-  paste0("col", seq_len(max(stringr::str_count(df1$col, "_")) + 1))

df1 |> separate_wider_delim(col, "_", names = cols, too_few = "align_start")
```

Comment: This is the error message I received in my actual database, which has many more columns and values. 
 
Error in `separate_wider_delim()`:
! Expected 2 pieces in each element of `col`.
! 79 values were too long.
i Use `too_many = "debug"` to diagnose the problem.
i Use `too_many = "drop"/"merge"` to silence this message.

Comment: I had hardcoded the output columns earlier. Can you try the updated answer where the output columns are dynamic and can change according to data provided you only have 1 column `path_finalcode` to be excluded.